# mysqli : know what caused the query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am using mysqli to query a database. I should insert values for a table "user" that has the primary key "username" and an unique string "email". When I execute the query:

```
$result= $this->connection->query($query_string);
if(!$result)
    trigger_error($this->connection->error);
```

If I try to insert a duplicate primary key I get:

> Notice: Duplicate entry 'ramy' for key 'PRIMARY' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Cinema/services/database.php on line 53

If instead I try to insert a duplicate email:

> Notice: Duplicate entry 'ramy.alzuhouri@student.unife.it' for key 'email' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Cinema/services/database.php on line 53

Now my question is: is there a way to know which is the problem, without parsing the string? In case of error I want to show to the user an error like "this username already exists". If the only way is to parse the string, how would you do it? I don't need the code, just a tip of how parsing it: should I just look for the work "primary" inside the error string, to conclude that I am attempting to insert a duplicate primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show to the user an error like "this username already exists".

A more common way to show such a message is to run a SELECT query first.

Answer (score -1):

Look for the word after "key". This should tell you where the error is. Maybe something like this:

```
function parse($errorstring){
$keyloc = strpos($errorstring,"key");
$afterkey = substr($errorstring,$keyloc+5);
return substr($afterkey,0,strpos($afterkey,"'"));
}
```

This will tell you which key was the duplicate. EDIT: Sorry, mixed up one of the functions!